# iphone media queries not working in Safari, ok in Chrome

Tags: css, ionic-framework, safari, media-queries, mobile-safari

I'm using the following @media queries for portrait/landscape on on iphone. They work fine in Chrome, but not in Safari when put in responsive/iphone mode. what am I doing wrong?

```
@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 414px) 
    and (max-device-height: 812px) 
  and (orientation: portrait)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

  .mq-landscape {
    display:none;
  }
}

@media only screen 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
    and (max-device-height: 414px) 
  and (orientation: landscape)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .mq-portrait {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Here's a stackblitz link:

- test: https://angular-ionic4-test-udtdf4.stackblitz.io
- edit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ionic4-test-udtdf4?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html&view=preview

reference: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/v4-iphone-media-queries-not-working-in-safari-simulator-ok-in-chrom/142730/2

Answer (score 0):

use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`

see this answer: [Safari Responsive Design Mode CSS media query 'device' not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220485/safari-responsive-design-mode-css-media-query-device-not-applied)

This is a corrected/working example for Safari:

```
@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 414px) 
    and (max-height: 812px) 
  and (orientation: portrait)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

  .mq-landscape {
    display:none;
  }
}
```