# Media Queries not working on actual iPhone device/Simulator

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-safari

I am having an issue with an Angular site with padding that only appears on mobile Safari. I am trying to address it with media queries but so far none on them are taking effect. I am running the iOS simulator with the iPhone 11. I have tried:

`@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait)`

`@media only screen 
    and (device-width: 414px) 
    and (device-height: 896px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)`

`@media only screen
     and (min-width: 375px)
     and (max-width: 767px)`

I got these from various searches for the iPhone 11. The simulator does not apply the change. I have also included this in the index.html:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

This is what the issue looks like on mobile safari, where the element is clipped off at the top.

[image: wrong image]

Interestingly, on the Chrome dev tools iPhone layout, it does apply the style properly. The issue is that the problem does not occur on Chrome so it ends up over applying the padding like shown:

[image]

So based on this, I think the queries are correctly applied but they just are not being accepted by mobile Safari. I'm not sure what is is that I'm missing. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

EDIT: 
The most recent attepmt with `min-width` instead of `min-device-width` still has not worked.

`@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 375px) 
  and (max-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait)`

Comment: this answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220485/safari-responsive-design-mode-css-media-query-device-not-applied

Comment: @jaideep_johny so I did notice that and tried variations with and without the device flag. Hasn't made a difference. I have updated the question with the most recent attempt.

Comment: @jaideep_johny. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: you can use css hack that works for only safari although it's just a patch so not recommended but it will get the work done. here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution? Can you help me?