# In Safari's Responsive Design Mode, how I make viewport width a specific px-size?

Tags: html, css, safari, safari-web-inspector

By clicking & dragging the sidebar I can resize viewport width. However, through clicking & dragging the side-bar it's too difficult/impossible to get a particular px-size I want. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: You can follow this link it can do your job.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220485/safari-responsive-design-mode-css-media-query-device-not-applied .

Comment: the viewport size is the size of the browser in pixel and as such controlled by the user. The user decides if he wants to makes his browser smaller and you cant take control of that. Thats why you have the large concept of responsive web design in the first place. However you can predefine how large wide and high the website should be and cause an overflwo with scroll bars by using `min-height` and `min-width`

Comment: @SajjadHosen This doesn't answer my question. Forget coding. I am in Safari's Responsive Design Mode. How do I alter it to a particular viewport width px size.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the values manually via the command line. First you can query the current values of the three non-iDevice presets with the following command:

```
defaults read ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations
```

which in my case returned the following:

```
(
        {
        rotated = 0;
        screenHeight = 1200;
        screenWidth = 1600;
    },
        {
        rotated = 0;
        screenHeight = 1536;
        screenWidth = 2732;
    },
        {
        rotated = 0;
        screenHeight = 2160;
        screenWidth = 3840;
        userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15";
    }
)
```

To change the values, you need to overwrite them. To do so, copy the result of the previous query, adjust it to your liking and write the values back to the plist by using the following command:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations '<paste your modified settings here>'
```

e.g.

```
defaults write ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist ResponsiveDesignCustomPresetConfigurations '(
        {
        rotated = 0;
        screenHeight = 1180;
        screenWidth = 1532;
    },
        {
        rotated = 0;
        screenHeight = 1536;
        screenWidth = 2732;
    },
        {
        rotated = 0;
        screenHeight = 2160;
        screenWidth = 3840;
        userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15";
    }
)'
```

**Note:**

- Values for screenHeight and screenWidth must be twice as high as your required dimensions, i.e. 1180 x 1532 if you want to have 590 x 766.
- Safari should be closed before setting the values.
- Tested on a MacBook running Mojave and Safari 14.0.1: creating a backup before doing this won't hurt!

Comment: This solution doesn't work on macOS 13 or higher.

Comment: Works for me in MacOS 13! Note that you will need to restart Safari to see the new values.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as selecting the size numbers and typing the size you need.

Not sure if this has always been the case, I'm using Safari 17.2.

[image: Screenshot of the size numbers in Responsive Design Mode]

Answer (score -2):

As of Safari 16.1, in responsive design mode, there should be some bars you can grab with your mouse on all sides of the viewport that you can hold and drag to the dimensions you'd like. It should automatically update the pixel dimensions at the top of the responsive design mode.

*I've only found a way to do it by hand, not entering the actual numbers so...thanks for another great web design tool Apple